# php How can I escape line break characters in a POST variable

Tags: php, html, forms, escaping, decode

I have a form that allows the user to enter what character to trim from the end of a string.  Here's a simple example. The form submits back to itself and alters the string **Testing 123,**  If you enter a comma into the form, you get back **Testing 123** (comma is removed). But what if that same string had a line break **\r\n** after the comma. I want to be able to enter **,\r\n** into the form and have it return **Testing 123**  So both the empty line and the comma are trimmed.  I assume it has to be escaped, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried removeslashes, htmlspecialchars, urldecode. I can't seem to get it.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['trim'])) {
echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."'>
<input type='text' name='trim'>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>";exit;}

$str="testing 123,
";
$str=rtrim($str,$_POST['trim']);
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = rtrim($str);
$str = rtrim($str, $_POST['trim']);
```

Will remove whitespace at the end of the string then whatever the user provides.

Comment: Yes, I can do it with trim, but as you can see from my code above, when `,\r\n` is entered into the form, and placed into the trim function it doesn't work.  For example, I can do this `$str = rtrim($str, ",\r\n");` but why doesn't this work `$str = rtrim($str,$_POST['trim']);`

Comment: I added another line, which I think is what you're asking.

Comment: Well, no, because the problem is the user gets to enter what he wants removed from an existing string.  If the string is `Hello World!` and you enter a `!` into the form, `Hello World` will be returned.  I want to be able to enter `,\r\n` in this situation to remove the comma and the line break in the string I mentioned in my code.  For some reason, you can't post `\r\n` as form data.

Comment: What if theres multiple occurrences of the string they input? Do you want them all removed? Just the last? Just ones at the end of the string?

Comment: The end of the string only, that's why I used rtrim

Comment: I've fixed it up for you.

Comment: Thanks, That's a decent solution.